# Extending readonly tuple types in TypeScript via Array

Tags: typescript, extension-methods, readonly

Suppose I have this definition of a `Color` type as well as acceptable string values for it:

```
const COLORS = ["Q", "R", "G", "B"] as const;
type Color = typeof COLORS[number]; // "Q" | "R" | "G" | "B"
```

The backing type of `COLORS` is, of course, a JavaScript array. I am using a polyfill for the `includes` method of arrays, declared in TypeScript as follows:

```
interface Array<T> {
    includes(member: T, fromIndex?: number): boolean
}
```

Now, I get why `includes` is not recognized as available on the `COLORS` instance — `COLORS` is `readonly` and nothing in the declaration of `includes` ensures that it is not mutating anything. However, **is there a way to declare this `includes` method such that it is available on `const`/`readonly` tuples?**

Comment: Actually `includes` can be used with readonly arrays! It's defined in TS `lib.es2016.d.ts` `ReadonlyArray` interface. Which target have you set in your tsconfig.json, have you adjusted your `lib` entry?

Comment: Yes, I am actually targeting ES5 on purpose here. But actually I found out I can just write the same interface declaration with `ReadonlyArray` instead of `Array`.

Comment: yeah, the polyfill is probably missing the readonly array type. What also works: You could specify the `lib` property in tsconfig.json compiler options to include "es2016.array.include", which provides types for `ReadonlyArray`. `"target": "es5", "lib": ["es5", "dom", "scripthost", "es2016.array.include"]`

Comment: Wow, I had no idea `"es2016.array.include"` could be listed as a lib! Where can I find the list of such detailed subparts of bigger libraries? OK but even then, I'll tend to want to keep the extended `interface` declaration close to the polyfill, in the same file, just to be sure I don't suddenly get one without the other.

Comment: You can have a look at all library configurations in the `lib` entry of [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). It's exactly for your purpose, where you `target` an older ES version, but use some of the "newer" ES libraries, which are shimmed by some polyfill. Of course, you can also write your global augmentation yourself, if its only one method like for `array.prototype.includes` (or use built in typings by the polyfill, if existent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments above:

Your const assertion `as const` creates a `ReadonlyArray` type, which has its own type definitions besides the declared `Array` interface. So you could add the global augmentation for `ReadonlyArray` as well:

```
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
    includes(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): boolean;
}
```

An alternative is to set the compiler option [`lib`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib) to include the built-in [`"es2016.array.include"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) API declarations. `lib` is useful, when you want to target an older ES version, but expect the runtime to also support some newer language constructs like `array.prototype.includes`, which could be polyfilled. In above compiler options docs, you also find the default `lib` settings depending on your `target`:

```
► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost
```

For target `ES5`, you can extend tsconfig.json accordingly:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5" ,
    // add es2016.array.include 
    "lib": ["es5", "dom", "scripthost", "es2016.array.include"]
    // ...
  }
}
```

PS: TypeScript lib declarations can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib) or simply by ctrl clicking on the type in VS Code, if you want to look them up.